# how to place Y-axis values within radar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

I have used the following example for my question: http://www.cmap.polytechnique.fr/~lepennec/R/Radar/RadarAndParallelPlots.html

```
mtcarsscaled <- as.data.frame(lapply(mtcars, ggplot2:::rescale01))
mtcarsscaled$model <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcarsmelted <- reshape2::melt(mtcarsscaled)

coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1) 
{
  theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
  r <- if (theta == "x") 
    "y"
  else "x"
  ggproto("CordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start, 
          direction = sign(direction),
          is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
}

plot <- ggplot(mtcarsmelted, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = model, color = model), fill = NA, size = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_line(aes(group = model, color = model), size = 2) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black",size=10), axis.text.y=element_text(size=14))+
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  coord_radar()

print(plot)
```

[image]

How do I move the values of the y-axis **onto the radar plot** so that they align with the major y-axis grid lines and get rid of the black box surrounding the plot?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the y-axis values as annotated text, and remove the black box by changing the `panel.border` parameter in `theme(...)`.

```
ggplot(mtcarsmelted, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = model, color = model), 
               fill = NA, size = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_line(aes(group = model, color = model), size = 2) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(ncol = 2)) +
  coord_radar() +
  theme_bw()+

  # annotate
  annotate("text", x = 0, 
           y = seq(0, 1, 0.25), 
           label = seq(0, 1, 0.25)) +

  # remove original y-axis text / ticks & black border
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black", size=10), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank())
```

[image: plot]

**Side note**: There are too many models in the same chart for this to be easily readable. If you are doing this for practice, that's fine. But if you intend to use it for communicating with others, you may wish to facet the plot so that only a few models are shown in each plot, or choose a different colour scheme that emphasizes only a few models of interest.

Comment: To build on the previous example, if I want to add an extra ring of labels above the outer edge of the graph, how would I do that? E.g if there was an extra category saying whether the car models were diesel, petrol, electric or hybrid and I wanted to show this on the graph. (this is just a hypothetical question, I want to apply this to a radial chart showing seasons).

Comment: @MariettePretorius Can you update your question with a sketch of what you mean? I'm not sure if I understand what you mean.